# XSLT - Count only duplicate values, and count them only once

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt

How do I get XSLT or XPath to return a count of 3 for the below data?

```
Kelly Watson
Andrew Lee
Andrew Lee
Susan Smith
Susan Smith
Susan Smith
Derin Gill
Derin Gill
William Jones
```

So only count the duplicates: Andrew, Susan, and Derin, and only count them once.

I've got the below which returns the data as a row.  But how to return the count has me stumped.

```
<xsl:variable name="MyValues" select="tokenize('~Kelly Watson~Andrew Lee~Andrew Lee~Susan Smith~Susan Smith~Susan Smith~Derin Gill~Derin Gill~William Jones', '~')"/>

<xsl:for-each select="$MyValues">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>

<xsl:value-of select="$DuplicateCnt"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you can use XSLT 2.0 or higher, so you could do something like:

```
<xsl:variable name="data">~Kelly Watson~Andrew Lee~Andrew Lee~Susan Smith~Susan Smith~Susan Smith~Derin Gill~Derin Gill~William Jones</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="groups">
    <xsl:for-each-group  select="tokenize($data, '~')" group-by=".">
        <group>
            <xsl:value-of select="count(current-group())" />    
        </group>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:variable>
<result>
    <xsl:value-of select="count($groups/group[. > 1])"/>
</result>
```

---

Or perhaps just:

```
<xsl:variable name="MyValues" select="tokenize('~Kelly Watson~Andrew Lee~Andrew Lee~Susan Smith~Susan Smith~Susan Smith~Derin Gill~Derin Gill~William Jones', '~')"/>
<result>
    <xsl:value-of select="count(distinct-values($MyValues)[count(index-of($MyValues, .)) > 1])"/>
</result>
```

Comment: Thats brilliant !!!  Follow up question, for the above how do I ignore case?

Comment: Start by`tokenize(lower-case($data))`.

Comment: Thank you (was just about to remove my question and post just that)

Answer (score 0):

There is an XPath 2 and later function `distinct-values`.

Comment: Thanks for looking.  However distinct-values returns all of the rows once.